# Unable to run gridview.databind(), eventargs error

Tags: asp.net

I have a listbox, that on selected change, runs a method to bind data to a gridview.  I get the error: **Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs'**.  I have other parts of my code that call another gridview.databind() from other controls, so I have no idea why it's throwing this error now?

```
Protected Sub lstEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As     EventArgs) Handles lstEmployees.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim x As Int16
    Dim startStr, endStr As String

    If txtAdminSelectedDate.Text <> "" Then
        dtWeeks = GetWeek(txtAdminSelectedDate.Text)
    End If

    If dtWeeks.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        x = dtWeeks.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString().IndexOf("-")
        endStr = dtWeeks.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString().Substring(x + 1, 11)
        startStr = dtWeeks.Rows(0).Item(1).ToString()
        dtWrkHours = GetHoursOfTheWeek(startStr, endStr, _user).Tables(0)
        gvAdmin.DataSource = dtWrkHours
        gvAdmin.DataBind()
        sStatus = String.Empty
        aStatus = String.Empty
        AdminTot = 0
        timeTot = 0
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Be careful not to get confused by "OnDataBound" and "OnRowDataBound", which happened to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot I asked this questions, but deleting RowDatabound and re-creating it fixed it.  I knew it was something weird.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you have a bad method signature for your grid.  Make sure it looks something like this:

Note: Pay special attention to the args: `ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs`

```
Public Sub xyz_DataBind(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles xyz.RowDataBound
   ...
End Sub
```

Comment: I do have that in the gridviewrowdatabound.  That's why I don't understand how it can be throwing the error?  Perhaps I can try deleting the RowDataBound, create it again?

Comment: You can try that.  It definitely seems out of whack.