# Can't access GridViewRowEventArgs event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to evaluate rows in GridView on DataBoundEvent but strangely instead of getting GridViewRowEventArgs in parameters list of event handling method I get EventArgs. If I alter the event type in the method signature the project does not compile saying that it expected EventArgs.
What could be the problem?

Comment: What happens if you try ti pass `GridViewRowEventArgs` anyway?

Comment: @shree.pat18 Project will not compile

Comment: Can you post the relevant code please? That might help to find any sources of error.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful and try not to get confused by OnRowDataBound and OnDataBound events from grid view.

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12842057/1257607) might help.